# Nexus 7 disconnects in Windows/Eclipse/ADB

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, adb, nexus-7

My Nexus 7 used to work fine in Windows 7 64bit, but now all of sudden when I connect it, it shows me the new device screen, it shows in Eclipse/ADB as Nexus 7 with Android 4.3 (correct), and then disappears a second or few later, with Device Disconnected in ADB log.

ADB then reports it as 'Offline' with OS unknown.

I have tried three different USB cabled, different USB ports, and on my Mac (not my main dev device though), the device works well. This is really frustrating. I tried setting the connection to PTP and Media Device. Both don't help.

Comment: do a adb kill-server and try again .It may ask for a RSA conformation.

Comment: Thanks I will do it next time. What I did instead is plugged another nexus 7 with 4.2.2 , and mine again 4.3. It's working again. Weird.

Comment: This is so weird.  I am having a very similar issue, except that it will usually let me deploy the app, but disconnects as soon as I try to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling and re-enabling usb-debugging.

Also try this:

```
    1: uninstall the driver in the device manager with option "delete the driver software for this device"
    reconnect the Nexus tablet
    2: let windows install a default driver which will be inadequate
    3: uninstall again the device in the device manager with the option "delete the driver software for this device"
    4: let windows try to find the driver, this process will fail
    5: go back to the device manager and right click the failed device and update driver
    6: choose the driver location in the android sdk directory (android/extra/google/usb_driver)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try next time. What I did instead is plugged another nexus 7, with 4.2.2 , and mine again with 4.3. It's working again. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Did it ask for the **RSA** Confirmation? That could be the thing that can prevent your device being showing up as connected

Comment: Thanks, but no, that device has been used with my pc many times before.